# cursors - %notfound is false even when row is not returned

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-cursor

I have a cursor that is used to get some information about all the groups of a certain class some other processing.
It is possible that the query backing the cursor may not return any rows,
because there are no groups or the class id doesn't exist.
In these cases, I want to raise an exception.
The problem is that even though I insert a class id that doesn't exist the function goes straight to the 'else' .
Does enyone have an idea why?
Here's what it looks like:

```
create or replace function ReturnGroupsOfClass(class_id_in in integer) return sys_refcursor 
is

      FunctionResult sys_refcursor;
      
      exception_no_class_found exception;
      pragma
      exception_init(exception_no_class_found,-2001);

begin    
      --a cursor of the group for class 'class_id_in'
      open FunctionResult for  
      select class_ID, group_day, group_startHour, count(*) as num_of_participants
      from Participant_In_Group 
      where  class_id=class_id_in
      group by class_ID, group_day, group_startHour
      order by class_ID;
    
      if(FunctionResult%notfound)
            then 
              raise exception_no_class_found;
        
      else
            dbms_output.put_line('you can view the cersor in the test window');
            
      end if;

      return(FunctionResult);
end ReturnGroupsOfClass;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `%notfound` cursor attribute is only set following a fetch from the cursor. As your function only opens the `FunctionResult` cursor, its found/notfound status remains undefined.

If you fetch a row before the check (for testing purposes only, as the cursor is no use to the caller if you do this), then you get your ORA-02001 exception:

```
create or replace function returngroupsofclass
    ( class_id_in in integer )
    return sys_refcursor
as
    functionresult sys_refcursor;

    exception_no_class_found exception;
    pragma exception_init(exception_no_class_found, -2001);

begin
    -- dummy cursor for testing:
    open functionresult for
        select dummy from dual where 1=2;
    
    declare
        testval dual.dummy%type;
    begin
        fetch functionresult into testval;
    end;

    if functionresult%notfound then
        raise exception_no_class_found;
    else
        dbms_output.put_line('you can view the cursor in the test window');
    end if;

    return functionresult;
end returngroupsofclass;
```

Testing in PL/SQL Developer:

```
begin
    :result := returngroupsofclass(class_id_in => :class_id_in);
end;
```

gives

```
ORA-02001: user SYS is not permitted to create indexes with freelist groups
ORA-06512: at "WILLIAM.RETURNGROUPSOFCLASS", line 23
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

I'm guessing 2001 might not be the error code you intended to link to this.

Comment: I believe user exceptions are supposed to be defined with values starting at -20000.  So perhaps a typo?